# Wordpress: How to Put a Function inside PHP?

Tags: wordpress, title, categories

with

```
     <?php

  if (is_category())

  echo single_cat_title();

  ?>
```

i can show up the current category title..

how can i insert the tag **single_cat_title()** into:

```
   <?php
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=10&showposts=4"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();

    if (in_category(10) && in_category(**Insert Here**)) { ?>
```

i tried it with

```
if (in_category(10) && in_category('.single_cat_title.')) { ?>
```

but no chance...
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to put it into a variable

```
$cat_title = single_cat_title();
```

then

```
if (in_category(10) && in_category($cat_title)) { ?>
```